# How to add action: click on chart and get data from that chart in MUI X charts BarChart?

Tags: typescript, next.js, dialog, bar-chart, mui-x-charts

I have a graph displaying data and I want when I click on a cloumn I can get the value of that column
and display that value to the console screen.
[Data Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIOoM.png)

I use MUI X charts BarChart and how can I handle the above problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are ongoing discussion on this topic: https://github.com/mui/mui-x/pull/11411